# With asm how to explicitly declare a variable parameter

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

For a method:

```
String invoke(Object... args)
```

When I use asm ClassVisitor to read this method, I see:

```
([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Yes the parameter args become a object array, as it is to say: variable parameter is a syntactic sugar of array.

But when I use javap to show the bytecode:

```
public java.lang.String invoke(java.lang.Object...);
```

I'm confused why javap know the args is variable Object..., not array type Object[]

**Answer：**

**Method access flag: ACC_VARARGS**

Comment: Is it possible that javap interprets any trailing `Object[]` as varargs?

Comment: The bytecode _has_ to store the information that it's varargs, or else how could another class compiling against your bytecode know that varargs is or isn't valid?

Comment: @Trinopoty I don't know, this is what I asked

Comment: It's pretty easy to test though. Make a method that has a trailing `Object[]` parameter and see if it becomes `Object...` in javap.

Comment: @Trinopoty No, Object[] is Object[], Object... is Object...。javap is clearly to distinguish

Comment: The bytecode definitely has flags for varargs.

Comment: Method access flags will include ACC_VARARGS for method accepting varargs. Check that flag.

Comment: @vbezhenar cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method access flag: ACC_VARARGS